# How-do-I-display-ranges-of-numbers-using-BETWEEN-Count and alias

Tags: sql-server-2008

How do I display ranges of numbers using `BETWEEN`, `COUNT` and `ALIAS` for ranges of numbers in the same column .
Say 10-19, 20-29, e.t.c 
Pls kindly help me!! I'm stuck

What I have tried:

```
Select Sex, Count(Age) as '10-19' from Table1
Where AGE BETWEEN 10 and 19
GROUP BY SEX
```

The code above works fine for me.

But for other ranges of numbers I am stuck. Pls my good programmer in the forum Pls help!!
The data is as follows

```
AGE Sex
----------
45  female 
45  male 
42  male 
40  male
24  male
45  female
10  male
25  male 
35  female 
23  male 
45  male 
43  male 
45  male 
44  male
```

I meant to load the data from excel workbook into datagridview by browsing for the excel files. Pls how do I go about it with vb. net?

I am able to browse for the excel files with the code below :

Private Sub BtnImport_Click(sender As Object,
Dim dialog As New OpenFileDialog()
                dialog.Filter = "Excel files |*

dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\"
                dialog.Title = "Please sélect
'your excel file."

If dialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then

Dim dt As DataTable 
dt = ImportExceltoDatatable(dialog.FileName) 
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt DataGridView1.Visible = True MsgBox(" done ! ", MsgBoxStyle.Information)

End If 
End Sub

Public Shared Function ImportExceltoDatatable(filepath As String) As DataTable 
Try
 Dim dt As New DataTable Dim ds As New DataSet()

Dim constring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & filepath &

";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;""" 
Dim con As New OleDbConnection(constring & "") con.Open()

Dim myTableName = con.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")

Dim sqlquery As String = String.Format("select sex, [1-4]= count(case when AGE between 1 And 4 then 1 end) , [5-9]= count(case when

AGE between 5 And 9 then 1 end) , [10-14]= count(case when AGE between 10 And 14 then 1 end)

,[15-19]= count(case when AGE between 15 And 19 then 1 end) 
,[20-24]= count(case when AGE

between 20 And 24 then 1 end)

From [" + Cbosheet.SelectedValue + " GROUP BY SEX", myTableName"]"

Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con)

da.Fill(ds) 
dt = ds.Tables(0)
 Return dt 
Catch ex As Exception MsgBox(Err.Description,

MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
 End Try 
End Function

It is generating errors, Pls someone should help out

Comment: Could you please add sample data from your original data? Is there anything you have tried so far?

Comment: I have edited my question sir. Thanks

Comment: Oh sorry. The data is as follows

Comment: The data is as follows

Comment: Age        sex
                                            12.          Male
                                         10.          Female
                                     23.           Male
                                        56.            Female
                                  15.            Male
                                      27.            Female

Comment: Add that data to your question so other users can easily read it too.

Comment: There's an oddly similar question out there under a completely different user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation

```
select 
    Sex, [10-19] = count(case when AGE between 10 and 19 then 1 end)
    , [20-29] = count(case when AGE between 20 and 29 then 1 end)
    --list other needed ranges
from 
    Table1
group by Sex
```

Comment: Thanks so much @uzi

Comment: I am gratefu to you l @uzi and everyone in the forum  for the answer. It helped.  But I am issues with integrating the code to load data from excel into my datagridview.

Comment: I meant to load the data from excel workbook into datagridview by browsing for the excel files. Pls how do I go about it